# Finding Tension in an Elastic String?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, string, elasticity

I know that this is a homework type question and I'm not asking a particular physics question, but I'm really desperate for help.

Here's the question:

[image]

I tried to divide the string to 2 parts with $O$ as the mid-point of $AB$.

Let $AO$=$T_{1}$ and $OB$=$T_{2}$, then $T_{2}-T_{1}=m\ddot x $. I don't know what to do next.

Here's the marking scheme: 
[image]

Comment: Sounds like the last sentence is strongly hinting for you to take the given set of equations and throw away any term involving $x^2$ or higher power.

Comment: I know that I will use the binomial expansion to find the terms until $x^{2}$, but I don't know how they got there in the first place (first line in the marking scheme).

Answer (score 3):

**Six years later**:

We are given that the natural length of the string is $2l$.
When the mass is suspended at the midpoint, $O$, of the string, the extension perpendicular to $AB$ is $x$. Let $M$ be the position of the mass at perpendicular extension $x$.
Then the extended length of the string from $A$ to $M$ (the hypotenuse of a triangle with sides $a$ and $x$) is:
$$AM=\sqrt(a^{2}+x^{2})$$
Since the string is extended at its mid-point, this is the same as the extension from M to B. Hence, the total length, $AMB$, of the extended string is
$$L=2\sqrt(a^{2}+x^{2})$$
The *extension* of the string from its natural length is
$$\delta {l}=2\sqrt(a^{2}+x^{2})-2l=2\left[{\sqrt(a^{2}+x^{2})-l} \right]$$

Using the formula for Tension in a string and substituting for $\delta {l}$:
$$\begin{align} T &=\lambda \frac{\delta {l}}{l} \\
&=\lambda \frac{2\left[{\sqrt(a^{2}+x^{2})-l} \right]}{2l} \\
&=\lambda \frac{\left[{\sqrt(a^{2}+x^{2})-l} \right]}{l}\end{align} $$

Finally, if  $x^{2} \ll 1$, this gives:
$$\begin{align} T &=\lambda \frac{\left[{\sqrt(a^{2})-l} \right]}{l} \\
 &=\lambda \frac{(a-l)}{l}
\end{align}$$